# Why my alias does not work with "sh -c"?

Tags: bash, sh

I don't understand why, on my server

```
php --version
```

gives me :

```
PHP 5.6.17
```

when

```
sh -c 'php --version'
```

gives me :

```
PHP 4.4.9
```

I just want to execute a command in php 5.6 and not in php 4.4 with "sh -c" command.

In other words, **why my php alias does not work with "sh -c" ?**

And **how to make it work with "sh -c" ?**

My .bash_profile :

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -r ${HOME}/.bashrc ] ; then
  source ${HOME}/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
USERNAME=""

export USERNAME BASH_ENV PATH
```

My .bashrc :

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

alias php='/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the output of `bash --version` and `sh --version`.

Your `sh` is not actually `bash`, so `.bashrc` isn't sourced when it starts, so the alias `php` is not defined in the new shell.

Comment: The right answer is "you don't". Alias expansion isn't enabled by default for a non-interactive shell, because they are only intended to save you a little bit of typing.